# Object sender y tomar texto

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo 3 botone diferentes pero quiero que al darle clic a alguno de ellos, el texto que este trae se guarde en una variable por medio del objeto `sender`

Uno de los botones seria por ejemplo el siguiente:

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn_eng" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="ENG" OnClientClick="showAndHide();" Width="185px" OnClick="Unnamed1_Click"></asp:Button>
```

y este es el evento que se realiza al darle clic:

```
protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button Btn_clic = (Button)sender;
        var name = Btn_clic;

        List.ListUsers listArea = new List.ListUsers();
        List<Data.Area> Area = listArea.AreaList();

        List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposFCHOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA = name && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();

        List<Button> Botones = new List<Button>();

        var TeamFCH = ListOfEquiposFCHOk.Select(x => x.TEAM).Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var team in TeamFCH)
        {
            Button newButton = new Button();
            newButton.Text = team;
            Botones.Add(newButton);
        }

        Panel1.Controls.Add(Botones[0]);
    }
```

ya lo logre guarder en la variable name pero al momento de querer concatenarla al query de linq no me lo acepta, y me arroja la linea roja debajo de ella

> Error 150 Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' and 'bool'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagino que tu problema está aqui:

```
List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposFCHOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA = name && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();
```

En la primera parte de tu clausula `&&` has puesto un operador de asignacion `=` en lugar de uno de comparación `==`:

```
List<Data.Area> ListOfEquiposFCHOk = Area.Where(x => x.AREA == name && x.STANDBY == 0).ToList();
```

Por otro lado, creo que en esta linea `var name = Btn_clic;` lo que quieres guardar es el id del boton o su texto, no el boton en si, asi que creo que debería ser:

```
var name = Btn_clic.ID;
```

o

```
var name = Btn_clic.Text;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, anteriormente ya lo tenia de esa manera pero de igual forma me marcaba el siguiente error `Error 150 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'`

Comment: Mira lo que acabo de editar @CesarGutierrezDavalos

Comment: oh ya veo, me faltaba el `.Text` muchisimas gracias por tu solucion!!

Comment: De nada,me alegro que te haya servido :)